# Rename a terminal in the Cloud9 IDE

Tags: unix, cloud9-ide

Seeing 'bash - "username"' in the terminal name is pretty useless when I'm running multiple windows, is there a way to rename those windows?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following function to your bashrc

```
setTitle() {
    # configure tmux to allow xterm set title sequence
    tmux set-window-option automatic-rename off
    tmux set-option allow-rename off 
    tmux set-option set-titles-string "#T"
    tmux set-option set-titles on
    # set terminal title
    echo -ne "\033]0;$@\007"
}
```

and then run `setTitle "my terminal name"`.

Sometimes bash prompt (`PS1`) contains `\033]0;...\007` as well, in that case you need to modify it to not allow overriding the title set by setTitle function